# CSS calc function for transition-delay

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to use the CSS `calc` function inside a `transition-delay` property.

Transition delay seems to work properly using the syntax:

```
transition-delay: 0.08s;
```

The calc property works for me when calculating sizes on the screen but I couldn't make it work for calculating time in this way:

```
transition-delay: calc(0.08s * 1);
```

Is it possible to get this result without pre-processors?

> UPDATE: Solved
>
> This is actually a valid syntax, but it isn't supported by some browsers including Firefox and IE.

Comment: There doesn't seem to a syntax error. What to expect to happen when multiplying by 1?

Comment: Have you tried moving "s" out of calc brakets? transition-delay: calc(0.08 * 1) s;

Comment: @Giorgio: That's not valid syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does work — `calc()` is expected to work with measurements<sup>[1]</sup> involving: **length**<sup>[2]</sup> (`px`, `em`, `ex`, `ch`, `rem`, `%`, `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax`, `mm`, `cm` and etc), **angles**<sup>[3]</sup> (`deg`, `rad`, `grad`, `turn`), **time**<sup>[4]</sup> (`ms`, `s`) and even **frequency** and **integers**.

If you look at the fiddle below, you can see that the base unit of the transition time is 100ms, but I have multiplied it by 20 to achieve a final transition time of two seconds using `calc()`. The transition-time is modified and calculated accordingly with no issues.

I suspect the reason why `calc()` is "not working" in your case is either (1) because the unit of measurement is not supported by a browser you are using, or that (2) you are multiplying the transition-time with a factor of 1, which of course returns the same value ;)

```css
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all calc(0.1s * 20) ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: #b13131;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Source:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/angle
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/time

---

**Update**: I would say that it is very likely that `calc()` is mostly used to calculate length measurements in browsers, and less commonly so for other kind of measurements, especially when it is still an experimental feature. Here is the results of a rather rudimentary browser test I have made so far:

- Chrome (39.0): **supported**
- Firefox:

  - 32.0.3: *not supported*
  - 35.0: *not supported*
- Internet Explorer (11.0): *not supported*
- Safari (8.0.2): *not supported*

Given the general lack of support for `calc()` in measurements other than length, I suggest that you stick to a CSS preprocessor, or JS (depending on deployment preference) to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work for me in Firefox or IE. It only works in Chrome. Looks like the two of them have some catching up to do, because it's certainly valid CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock Yup. Just updated my answer to account for the fact that `calc()` might not work with measurements of time in some browsers. Real shame though.

Comment: Seems like you are right, my code works on Chrome but not on other browsers.
Maybe because this bug was already solved at Webkit
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138784

Comment: Firefox bug tracking concerning this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956573

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it works fine for me. Here check the code

```
<div id="circle"></div>

#circle{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#000;
border-radius:50%;
margin:50px auto;
transition:all calc(1s*2) ease;
}
#circle:hover{
background:#555;
}
```

Hope this was useful to you http://jsfiddle.net/p243bk8g/1/